# yii: count value array depend on index group number

Tags: php, arrays, yii, sum

I have table from mysql like below:

```
id | name | grade | k1 | k2 | k3 | s1| s2 | s3| e1 | e1 | e3 |
1  |  Aa  |    5  |  1 | 0  | 5  | 3 | 2  | 1 |  0 | 6  | 1  |
2  |  Bb  |    1  |  1 | 3  | 5  | 3 | 5  | 3 |  4 | 6  | 1  |
3  |  Cc  |    2  |  1 | 4  | 2  | 2 | 2  | 4 |  0 | 6  | 1  |
4  |  Dd  |    4  |  1 | 3  | 5  | 3 | 3  | 1 |  0 | 6  | 1  |
5  |  Ee  |    3  |  1 | 5  | 2  | 1 | 0  | 5 |  0 | 6  | 1  |
6  |  Ff  |    2  |  1 | 3  | 1  | 3 | 4  | 2 |  0 | 6  | 1  |
7  |  Gg  |    5  |  1 | 1  | 5  | 5 | 2  | 1 |  0 | 6  | 1  |
```

Using FOR and FOREACH looping, i do able to show all row. But in final view/table i want to

```
SUM [k1,k2,k3], SUM[s1,s2,s3] and SUM[e1,e2,e3]
```

So it will place new colum as K, S and E in each row.

Here are my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < Evaluation::model()->count(); $i++) {
    foreach (Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->from('evaluation')
        ->queryAll() as $item) {
         // Row-Column start here
         // id | name | grade | K  | S  | E  |
    }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love the query builder. So here is one of the solution.

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->
    select('id, name, grade, (k1+k2+k3) AS K, (s1+s2+s3) AS S, (e1+e2+e3) AS E')->
    from(MyModel::model()->tableName())->
    queryAll();

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I change my code based on your suggestion: for ($i = 0; $i < Evaluation::model()->count(); $i++) {
    foreach (Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('id, name, grade, k1+k2+k3 AS K, s1+s2+s3 AS S, e1+e2+e3 AS E')->from('evaluation')
        ->queryAll() as $item) {
         // Row-Column start here
         // id | name | grade | K  | S  | E  |
    }
} //give me this error: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Comment: No, I did mistype. I just realize that on Yii, the column names will be enclosed with the backtick `\``. So it will rise the Unknown column error if we don't parenthesized `k1+k2+k3`

Answer (score 0):

```
select k1+k2+k3, s1+s2+s3, e1+e2+e3 from t
```

and it is not yii question, it is about MySql

If you want to express it in Yii, you can

```
Yii:app()->createCommands()
    ->select('k1+k2+k3, s1+s2+s3, e1+e2+e3')
    ->from('t')
    ->queryAll();
```